Is there a way from quarkus to send an event to a device, specifically a tablet?
I want to create a kind of webhook that allows me to send an event with data to a tablet. I want to do this, but there is also a problem, and that is that there can be several tablets and I need to identify the tablets somehow. Let's say I store the tablet information in a table and have it available. How can I do this?
I expect my tablet to receive the event from my Quarkus API, and send it the necessary information in a JSON.

I think you need to be a lot more specific about your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You're looking for SSEs (Server-Side Events) or Websockets.
To handle the tablets needing unique identifiers, just have them create an UUID and store it somewhere in the device's memory or cache if you don't want any account creation shenanigans, and then use that for its requests.
